# Azure Durable Function logging every single Log multiple times when using Fan-Out pattern for an Activity

Tags: python, python-logging, azure-durable-functions

I'm trying to use Azure Durable Functions to orchestrate my workflows and I'm able to execute the functions according to my needs, however, all my Logs (from python's `logging` package) are rewritten every time I call one of my Fan-Out Activities.

I have two inputs from the starter HTTP request: `limit` and `ta`.
After reading those inputs, I start my mappers (from my sqlalchemy ORM, don't know if this is the best practice or if I should start my mappers somewhere else) and start calling some activities to fetch and transform some data.

I use `Function chaining` and `Fan-Out/Fan-In` patterns.

My Orchestrator function is as follows:

```
def an_orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
  
  input_= context.get_input()
  
  limit= input_['limit']

  ta= input_['ta']
  
  # Function Chaining:

  activity_one= yield context.call_activity(
    name= 'GetSomeDataFromADataBase',
    input_= {
      'limit': limit,
      'ta': ta
    }
  )
  
  activity_two_first_input= ...
  activity_two_second_input= ...
  ...
  fan_out_info= [... for foo in activity_one] 
  # A list is built from the returned value of an Activity
  
  activity_two= yield context.call_activity(
    name= 'GetSomeMoreDataFromADataBase',
    input_= {
      'activity_two_first_input': activity_two_first_input,
      'activity_two_second_input': activity_two_second_input,
      ...: ...
    }
  )
  
  activity_three= yield context.call_activity(
    name= 'GetSomeMoreDataFromADataBaseWithNoInput',
    input_= None
  )

  # Fan-Out:
  tasks= []
  results= []
  for foo in fan_out_info:
    
    # some transformation is done here with the returned values of my previous Activities
    fan_out_input_one= ...
    fan_out_input_two= ...
    ...
    
    tasks.append(
      context.call_activity(
        name= 'FanOutActivity',
        input= {
          'input_one': fan_out_input_one,
          'input_two': fan_out_input_two,
          ...: ...
  
  for task in tasks:
    try:
            
      yield task
            
      if task.state== TaskState.SUCCEEDED:
                
        results.extend(task.result)

    except Exception as e:
            
            logging.exception("FooBar Activity failed: %s", e)

  # do something with the result:
  ...
```

My Durable Function executes as desired, but my logs are redundant, and I have no idea why.

I've tried to find a solution but was not able to.

From the Logs, it seems the Orchestrator is being executed each time I call an Activity from the Fan-Out part, since the logs show:

```
Executing 'Functions.AnOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=abc123)

Executed 'Functions.AnOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=abc123, Duration=...ms)

Executing 'Functions.AnOrchestrator' (Reason='(null)', Id=def456)

Executed 'Functions.AnOrchestrator' (Succeeded, Id=def456, Duration=...ms)
```

Also, if I log the DurableOrchestrationClient context from inside the orchestration function, it is clear that there are multiple contexts on different memory addresses, meaning the code is being executed multiple times and instantiating multiple Orchestrators.

EDIT:

After debugging my DurableFunction, I noticed that after every Activity execution, the debugger goes back to the beginning of the Orchestrator script and tries to execute every step again, and it seems to skip the Activities and returned objects deserialization that already happened, similar to a caching for these steps. However, I still don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Durable Functions are weird.

Every time your function gets to a `yield` it essentially stops. If it gets there it checks its *semi*internal log to see if it's already done that step. If it has then it returns what it already did rather than starting the worker. If it hasn't then it runs the worker task and stops. When a worker is done then it puts its results in that log and starts the orchestrator again. That's why you can't do anything random, IO bound, or CPU intensive in the orchestrator, because, by design, its repeating the orchestrator all the time.

As such, it is expected that you'll see the log activity you're seeing.

As an aside, I gave up durable functions. One big issue with it is that it doesn't scale well. I'd have an orchestrator that would fan-out to a few hundred worker processes. You'd think it would spawn a bunch of extra workers for that or hold back in accordance with memory usage, but it wouldn't. Instead, it'd try to run all of them on the same worker and crash for memory. It doesn't crash well either. It'd complain about non-deterministic workflows and then you have to manually go delete all the state info from storage and restart the function.

In my opinion, durable functions are more hassle than they're worth. Instead, use queue triggers for fan out tasks. They scale very nicely and don't push so many tasks that you run out of ram. Until I used queue triggers I've never seen any apps spawn out to more then 2-3 workers. With queue triggers, it will quickly get to the max workers.

Back to your problem, instead of an orchestrator you'd make a timer or http trigger (or anything but orchestration) as a quasi-orchestrator and use

```
import asyncio
from azure.storage.queue.aio import QueueClient as QC, QueueServiceClient as QSC
from azure.storage.queue import TextBase64EncodePolicy
```

Then your fan-out would be more like this:

```
# Fan-Out:
aioserv= QSC.from_connection_string(conn_str=storage_account_key)
async with aioserv.get_queue_client("queue_name_in_storage", message_encode_policy=TextBase64EncodePolicy()) as aioclient:
for foo in fan_out_info:
# You'd probably want to do the transformations in the next function

    asyncio.create_task(
        aioclient.send_message(foo , time_to_live=seconds)
    )
```

Then you'd have another function that is a queue trigger off of "queue_name_in_storage" which takes `foo` as its input and does whatever you need it to do. I don't know enough about what you're ultimately trying to do so it's hard to recommend the next step for "fanning-in" but the allure of durable functions being eternal and well organized, in my experience, is belied by its inability to scale, its bad crash handling, and the incoherent logs of the orchestrator.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, however, It is not up to me to choose usage of Durable Functions. If I use a log system such as New Relic, I'll be ok I guess. 

I'll try to use it, but if I get stuck (I also need quite a few workers for parallel executions) I'll evaluate another option.


PS.: Do you know any way to silence these 'Executing Orchestrator...' and 'Executed Orchestrator...' logs? I've been searching for it, but could not understand how to do it.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I mean if you're trying to track down logs it means you're having other issues and doing a workaround to avoid seeing the repeats isn't going to help the underlying issue. Believe me, I speak from experience. Further, the more things you're trying to do in parallel, the worse it's going to be. The algorithm they use to spawn new VMs is awful with durable functions.

Comment: I didn't know the telemetry worked this way, so I was confused as to what was going on, more than I needed to track down issues. I'll try to adjust the log levels, something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#solutions-with-high-volume-of-telemetry) in order to clear my terminal. I do believe you, but for the moment I'll follow this approach. Again, thank you very much.